# How can site disable text selection if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I found a website, if you want more precisely I can paste a link to it but I would rather not be a reason for increased traffic on it. I wanted to copy some text from it but they disabled selecting it. When I disabled Javascript on my Chrome, it still didn't allow me to select their text. I tried also with Firefox but I got the same result. I did eventually succeeded to copy it with Chrome Web Tools but my question is how exactly they did it even with Javascript disabled or am I just missing something?

Comment: Without seeing the page in question, we can only guess. My guess would be that they used the [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) CSS property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

`user-select: none;` CSS rule will disable selection, so it can be added by default

```html
<body style="user-select: none">
  javascript disabled
</body>
```

And with javascript removing that style:

```js
document.body.style.userSelect = null;
```

```html
<body style="user-select: none">
  javascript enabled
</body>
```